# Populate HTML SELECT using mysql and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

what is the best, tidiest way to populate a html select tag with items from the database?

For example, if I have the following php:

```
  $sql="SELECT a.athleteId, a.fName, a.lName FROM Athletes a, SupportStaff s, StaffAthletes sa WHERE sa.staffId = $id AND a.athleteId = sa.athleteId"; 
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Then:

1. How do I populate the drop down menu with the list of tuples retrieved from the relation?
2. How should the php, html and jQuery be integrated?

I have the following, but it doesn't work- It just displays a blank page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL)
session_start();
//connect to database
function connect() {
  $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "d", "a") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("PDS", $dbh); 
  return $dbh;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $dbh = connect();
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $sql="SELECT a.athleteId, a.fName, a.lName FROM Athletes a, SupportStaff s, StaffAthletes sa WHERE sa.staffId = $id AND a.athleteId = sa.athleteId"; 
  $result=mysql_query($sql); 

  $options="";   
  $i = 1;
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $f=$row["fName"]; 
    $l=$row["lName"]; 
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$i\">".$f.' '.$l."</OPTION>"; 
    $i++;
  }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <script src = "jQuery.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#go").click(function(e){
       if($("#selectathlete option:selected").val() == "0"){
         alert("Please Select An Athlete");
       }else{
         //set hidden textfield
         $("form#profile").submit();
       }
       });
   });
  </script>
  <title>Personal Diary System - Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <p>Select An Athlete: 
  <SELECT ID ="selectathlete" NAME="athletes"> 
  <OPTION VALUE="0">Choose</OPTION>
  <?php echo($options);?>
  </SELECT>
  </p>
  <form id = "profile" name="input" action="viewathleteprofile.php" method="post">
  <input type = "hidden" id = "athleteId">
  <input type = "button" name = "go" id = "go" value = "Go">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been debugging for hours and it just doesn't work...

Comment: The population itself isn't related to jQuery. Also, try prepending `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);`.

Comment: use ajax service page instead?

Comment: A small example http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should try to `error_reporting(E_ALL)` your page, so that you can see any and all errors your page comes across.
2. What's `connect()`? did you mean `mysql_connect()`?
3. (Kinda unrelated) You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions, use [MySQLi](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (Good) or [PDO](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (Awesome).

Comment: 1. Where do I place that line of code?
2. connect() is a custom function that connects to db - it works.
3. Noted...

Comment: At the very top of the script. @user

Comment: I edited my code - see above. I added the line but it still prints nothing

Comment: @user, then I would suggest trying to execute it through the php CLI.

Answer (score 1):

when i get stuck on server 500 errors i go over to http://phpcodechecker.com/ and paste in the page.  when i did that on what code you have now, it complained about a missing ; on line 2.

another tip: you can use this syntax style for slightly less complex output:
  $out = "text {$var} {$var2} {$array['index']}".DEFINITION_ONE

surprisingly this works for html attributes which we expect to output as "value" e.g.
  $options .= "{$i} {$f}

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your file is a .php, not .html
2. don't forget "`<?php`" at the top of page.
3. try to write "`echo 'hello';`" at the top your page to see if it prints.

this seems trivial, but as you seem to have pasted the full code, i just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps $_SESSION['username'] isn't set? You don't have a closing brace on that if statement, so if isset($_SESSION['username']) returns false, the whole page never gets displayed.